# Set value to 0 if it is less than zero in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have this query

```
SELECT
    TestPackageId,
    SUM(ROUND((Quantity - (QuantityBeforeDone + QuantityExistInSite + QuantitySpool + TotalMIV)), 3)) AS Shortage
FROM ...
```

The shortage value sometimes is negative. So if the value is negative it should be 0.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a `CASE` expression?

Comment: @FelixPamittan should i change my main code if i change it to case?

Comment: Just minor modification: `SELECT
 TestPackageId,
 CASE 
  WHEN SUM(ROUND((Quantity - (QuantityBeforeDone + QuantityExistInSite + QuantitySpool + TotalMIV)), 3)) > 0 THEN
   SUM(ROUND((Quantity - (QuantityBeforeDone + QuantityExistInSite + QuantitySpool + TotalMIV)), 3)) > 0 
  ELSE 0
 END AS Shortage
FROM ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A case expression is the way to go:

```
   CASE WHEN SUM(ROUND((Quantity - (QuantityBeforeDone + QuantityExistInSite + QuantitySpool + TotalMIV)), 3)) < 0 then 0 else SUM(ROUND((Quantity - (QuantityBeforeDone + QuantityExistInSite + QuantitySpool + TotalMIV)), 3)) end
```

Comment: I want to just check this part not whole sum statement\ROUND((Quantity - (QuantityBeforeDone + QuantityExistInSite + QuantitySpool + TotalMIV)), 3)

Comment: Which part do you want to check? Your shortage column is a sum. You have to repeat it twice because there is no way to use it as a variable without another query.

Comment: You can't use the non sum amount without grouping by that item

Answer (score 1):

use the formula

```
(SUM(ROUND((
   Quantity - (QuantityBeforeDone + QuantityExistInSite + QuantitySpool + TotalMIV)), 3))+ 
 ABS(SUM(ROUND((
 Quantity - (QuantityBeforeDone + QuantityExistInSite + QuantitySpool + TotalMIV)), 3)))) / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

> Case expression

Here is an example:

```
case when value = 0 then 'zero' when value < 0 then 'negative' else 'positive' end
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who prefer one short line instead of long CASE statements or duplicating value in ABS() (formula logic may change some day and need not to forget change it everywhere in code etc.).

Use `isnull(nullif(sign({column name}),-1),0)` :

```
select isnull(nullif(sign(-100),-1),0) as negative
select isnull(nullif(sign(0),-1),0) as zero
select isnull(nullif(sign(100),-1),0) as positive
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it returns 1 on positive values, instead of the actual value of the column

Comment: Yes, it's only for multiplier, which it used before real value:

isnull(nullif(sign({column name}),-1),0) * {column name}